# ReferenceError: MockV3Aggregator is not defined , getting this error while deploying mock contract

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy, mock, smart-contract

Getting this error while deploying mock contract

```
ReferenceError: MockV3Aggregator is not defined
```

Imported MockV3Aggregator from chainlink's github and now it's in my node modules also.
This is my deploy script

```js
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, DECIMALS, INITIAL_ANSWER } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments}) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts()

    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        log("Local network detected! Deploying mocks...")
        await deploy("MockV3Aggregator", {
            contract: MockV3Aggregator,
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: [DECIMALS, INITIAL_ANSWER],
        })
        log("Mocks deployed!!")
    }
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]
```

and this is my helper-hardhat-config.js

```js
const developmentChains = [ "hardhat", "localhost" ]
const DECIMALS = 8
const INITIAL_ANSWER = 200000000000

module.exports = {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
    DECIMALS,
    INITIAL_ANSWER,
}
```

and command used to deploy is

```
yarn hardhat deploy --tags mocks
```

Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it,
After removing this line from deploy script, it is perfectly deployed

```
contract: MockV3Aggregator,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution can solve the problem, but that's not the key point. MockV3Aggregator should be "MockV3Aggregator"